# Best approach to follow in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working on simple transform SSIS package to import data from one server and load to another server.  Only one table is used on each.
I wanted to know, as its just refreshing of data, does the old data in the table needed to be deleted before loading, I needed expert advice about what should I do.  Should I truncate the old table or use delete?  What other concerns should I keep in mind?
Please give the justification for your answers, it will help to fight technically with my lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the requirements are.

Do you need to keep track of any changes to the data? If so, truncating the data each time, will not allow you to track the history of your data. A good option in this case is to stage the source data in a separate table/database and load your required data in another structure (with possible history tracking, e.g., a fact table with slowly changing dimensions).

Truncating is the best option to remove data, as it's a minimally logged operation.

Comment: Looks good option as we dont need any history/tracking for table. Thanks